# ORA-00449: background process 'MMAN' unexpectedly terminated with error 7446

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

One of our Oracle servers went down rather badly last night, and we have been unable to bring it online since. Attempting to startup each instance results in:

```
SQL> Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> ORA-00449: background process 'MMAN' unexpectedly terminated with error 7446
ORA-07446: sdnfy: bad value '' for parameter .
SQL> Disconnected
```

After running this, none of the instances are online. The listener reports that is running, at least.

The first instance (asdb) in the order has a number of (mostly repetitive sections) in its alert.log, but nothing in there seems particularly likely. The other instances have blank (but writeable) alert.log files.

Where should I investigate to try and get this back online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it seems that the bdump and cdump directories for each instance had been deleted. I don't know who (or what) did that, but restoring them fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution - I hope you get to the bottom of it and if so please edit your answer here to let us know. In the meantime I suggest you make your answer as 'accepted'